# Tokens when setting up activity scheduled reminder

Tags: civicase, scheduled-reminders

Using Drupal 7.34 and CiviCRM 4.6.4.

We are using civiCase and want to send a reminder to the manager of a case. When I try and set up a template, there does not seem to be a way of telling the manager which case it is they are being reminded about. The token *{contact.display_name}* generates the name of the manager not the client they are dealing with. So although I can remind the manager to do something, I cannot say which client the reminder relates to.

I have explored the possibility of a custom token but cannot see a way around this.

Any suggestions?

Dave Smith

Answer (score 1):

Yes do add additional values to the template you need to create a tokens on your own by creating new extension or by adding token hook in the existing extension for example for creating tokens please refer to the below link

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Customized+%28and+Custom%29+Tokens

https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/

If you haven't created New extension please refer to the below link

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This puts me into coding which I do not have access to (and is a bit beyond me anyway!). I am surprised that scheduled reminders would not automatically allow a reminder to be sent to the manager with enough details to know what the reminder is about. Maybe I am just not setting up the reminders correctly - although I  have been trying to do that for days ...

Comment: it seems the link changed to  https://civicrm.org/blog/colemanw/create-your-own-tokens-for-fun-and-profit

Comment: I have updated the links please have a look and if you have any issue please let me know - thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [CiviToken](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken) extension by Fuzion may help - or may be a good place to contribute any new tokens cre